# Create pandas dataframe from list of tuple of nested lists

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have this data below, which is a list with 4 elements. These elements are tuple which items are list them self...

```
data = [(['a', 'b', 'c'],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  ['aa', 'bb'],
  ['00', '03', '0000', '0006']),
 (['e', 'f', 'g'],
  [2, 1, 4, 4, 6],
  ['qq', 'er'],
  ['10', '04', '3340', '9009']),
 (['w', 'd', 'c'],
  [5, 6, 55, 1, 6],
  ['rr', 'rr'],
  ['55', '11', '6788', '7789']),
 (['l', 'a', 's'],
  [29, 2, 9, 4, 3],
  ['yy', 'uu'],
  ['33', '67', '0000', '0237'])]
```

I want to convert it to dataframe in such a way that each element is broken onto column of the dataframe. For example; `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

will result into a dataframe with four columns. What I want is for each column to be broken into columns of the dataframe as seen below in red lines...
[image]

That is to say, above dataframe will have each column sub divided into the number of items that made up the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten nested `list`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[item for sublist in l for item in sublist] for l in data])
print (df)
  0  1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11    12    13
0  a  b  c   1   2   3   4   5  aa  bb  00  03  0000  0006
1  e  f  g   2   1   4   4   6  qq  er  10  04  3340  9009
2  w  d  c   5   6  55   1   6  rr  rr  55  11  6788  7789
3  l  a  s  29   2   9   4   3  yy  uu  33  67  0000  0237
```

**Timings**:

```
data = data * 100

In [128]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([[item for sublist in l for item in sublist] for l in data])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.03 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ1 
In [137]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda d:  list(chain.from_iterable(d)), data)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.97 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ2 
In [129]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(list(zip(*data)), axis=1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ3 
In [130]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([np.concatenate(d) for d in data])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.9 ms per loop


data = data * 10000

In [121]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([[item for sublist in l for item in sublist] for l in data])
10 loops, best of 3: 99.2 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ1 
In [139]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda d: list(chain.from_iterable(d)), data)))
10 loops, best of 3: 95.8 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ2 
In [122]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(list(zip(*data)), axis=1))
10 loops, best of 3: 150 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ3 
In [123]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([np.concatenate(d) for d in data])
1 loop, best of 3: 560 ms per loop
```

Comment: I've added another option, could you please update if it isn't too much of a hassle?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec

Comment: Here it is minimal difference with nested flattenting.